# Simple autowire="byName" doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a POJO with a field `message`:

```
package com.packt.lifecycle;

public class HelloWorld {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

In my app context XML I have 2 bean definitions:

```
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.packt.lifecycle.HelloWorld" autowire="byName">
</bean>

<bean name="message" class="java.lang.String" >
   <constructor-arg value="auto wired1" />
</bean>
```

However, the autowiring by name for some reason doesn't work. The following code displays null:

```
AbstractApplicationContext  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
HelloWorld world = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
System.out.println(world.getMessage());
```

Comment: try<constructor-arg value="auto wired1" type="java.lang.String"/>

Comment: The message bean is set correctly, it's the autowire that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not autowire strings like that.
Check out the [exceptions for auto-wiring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-exceptions).

I think auto-wiring of constant primitives are discouraged so that they are created like property values - that will force you to externalize your constants to a property file which sounds more appropriate.

Rather define your message in a properties file as :

```
message.key=Hello World
```

Then load your properties with a `PropertyConfigurer` and then autowire constant properties as :

```
@Value("${message.key}")
private String message;
```

or provide a default value (hard coded) as

```
@Value("${useDefault:Hello World}")
private String message;
```

Answer (score 0):

Autowire doesn't work because the property is not configured in Spring. Put the annotation on the field or method to let the Spring know that this property needs autowiring.

```
@Component
public class HelloWorld {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

To make annotations work you need something like

```
<!--<context:annotation-config/>-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.packt.lifecycle"/>
```

Comment: Ok, you can also put annotation on a method, where you can trace the autowiring.

Answer (score -1):

Just add your property within your bean definition:

```
<bean id="helloWorld" class="com.packt.lifecycle.HelloWorld" autowire="byName">
  <property name="message" value="auto wired1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I understand, that works, I just want to find out why autowire doesn't work.